# Query multiple joins or add extra column

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a database with tables A,B,C and D (all one to many relation). A has many B, B has many C and C has many D. Now I want to add another table Z. Table Z will have many A and table A could be a parent to another A recursively.

Now if I wanted to query all D's related to all A's which have the same Z as another A I have to get the id of Z and query all the relations. Would it be faster if table D had a column with the id of Table Z? I could only query all D's with id of Z. Would it be faster than querying all the relations? Is it correct to do so?

A is like a user, Z is like a group, and D could be a post. If i wanted to get all the post of all the users in the same group as my user is it better (performance) to query by the relations or is adding group id to the post table a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

If D is a post, I don't think it's a good idea to add a group to the post. The post was made by an user, not by a group. And you can implement queries that allow you to filter by a group. The query will not be so simple as it would be if you had the group id at the post table, but that's the way I would do it :)